# Using vector to represent matrix

Tags: c++

Why does this gives me `error: ‘matrixSize’ is not a type` ?

```
int matrixSize = 10;
vector<vector<double> > matrix(matrixSize, vector<double>(matrixSize));
```

What is the problem here? on cppreference I dont see that vvector constructor requires any type

Comment: GCC 4.9.3 -std=c++14, compiles just fine.

Comment: This should not give you any errors. Are you sure this error comes from these lines of code. Maybe something else gives you this error?

Comment: Include the actual compiler vomit, not just an interpretation of it.  Code looks fine to me so we really need the error to help you.

Comment: Yes, this compiles just fine with GCC 5.3.1 as well (no CXX14 flag)

Comment: `error: ‘matrixSize’ is not a type` maybe there is something like: `vector< matrixSize >` inside your code? This could give such errors

Comment: When i change it to 
    vector<vector<double> > matrix(5); i get this   error: expected identifier before numeric constant|error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before numeric constant|

Comment: Please post a [mcve].  Adding the appropriate include files gives no such error: http://ideone.com/YZ30Mi

Comment: @lllook  http://ideone.com/1I8WoS  Again, post a full example instead of having to go back and forth on this.

Comment: @lllook Your problem is somewhere else. Give us more code.

Comment: http://ideone.com/BZWoXO

Comment: @llook You should have taken the time to reduce it down to this:  http://ideone.com/dxs95A  This is the first thing any programmer should do if they get a compiler error.  Reduce it down to the bare minimum of code that reproduces the error.  There is no need to post a snippet, or give us a link to a 50 line program using maps and streams.  Every C++ compiler error can be reproduced with just a few lines of code.

Comment: When nesting STL container, you need to be aware that each STL container has a significant overhead, therefore if your matrix is large, it is better to use a single chunk of memory (or a single vector) and do the indexing on your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the definition of matrix inside the constructor. Change:

```
vector<vector<double> > matrix(matrixSize, vector<double>(matrixSize));
```

to:

```
vector<vector<double> > matrix;
```

And then inside the constructor:

```
CParser(const string & str) : iss(str) {
        this->matrix = vector<vector<double>>(this->matrixSize, vector<double>(this->matrixSize));
}
```

Comment: thank you, is "this->" really needed? I can initiaize matrixSize in the initializer list of the constructor

Comment: In some cases yes. But I think it's good practise to use it everytime. Notice that `matrix` and `matrixSize` are both members of `CParser` that's why I used `this`.

Comment: Yes, you can initialize matrixSize in the initialization list of the constructor

Comment: @DimChtz The preferred method is to use the initialization list.  The goal of the OP is to initialize the member, and the initialization list's purpose is to do that -- initialize.  You should update the answer to include this.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Never said the opposite :)

Comment: why is it good practice to use this->, can you initialize other class member in other class constructor?